# How to change the background properties of an mfc application

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

CURRENT UI

[image]

NEW UI

[image]

I want to change the background color of a button in MFC application. I have  created my user interface(UI) in MFC .I have added every controls from the toolbox.But the problem is that i want to change the background and foreground properties of a button and window.How it is possible?

please help me to change the properties of controls in MFC.In windows application we can directly change the properties in the property window.
But in the case of MFC application that is not possible.

please help me..i have not enough experience in MFC application development.....
Thanks in advance......................

### code from dialer.h

```
   class CButtonDialer : public CButton
{
// Construction
public:
    CButtonDialer();

// Attributes
public:
    CButton m_button;

//  CButton IDC_KEY_1;
    CBrush m_brush;

// Operations
public:

// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CButtonDialer)
    public:
    virtual void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct);


// Implementation
public:
    virtual ~CButtonDialer();
// Generated message map functions
protected:
    //{{AFX_MSG(CButtonDialer)
        // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove member functions here.
    //}}AFX_MSG
    afx_msg BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);
    CFont m_FontLetters;
    CMapStringToString m_map;
    HTHEME m_hTheme; 


    void OpenTheme() { m_hTheme = OpenThemeData(m_hWnd, L"Button"); }
    void CloseTheme() {
        if (m_hTheme) { CloseThemeData(m_hTheme); m_hTheme = NULL; }
    }
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    virtual void PreSubclassWindow();
    afx_msg LRESULT OnThemeChanged();
    afx_msg void OnMouseMove(UINT,CPoint);
    afx_msg void OnSize(UINT type, int w, int h);
};
```

### code from dialer.cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ButtonDialer.h"
#include "Strsafe.h"
#include "const.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CButtonDialer

CButtonDialer::CButtonDialer()
{
    //255,255,255
    m_brush.CreateSolidBrush(
        (173, 41, 41));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("1"),_T(""));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("2"),_T("ABC"));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("3"),_T("DEF"));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("4"),_T("GHI"));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("5"),_T("JKL"));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("6"),_T("MNO"));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("7"),_T("PQRS"));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("8"),_T("TUV"));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("9"),_T("WXYZ"));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("0"),_T(""));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("*"),_T(""));
    m_map.SetAt(_T("#"),_T(""));
}

CButtonDialer::~CButtonDialer()
{
    CloseTheme();
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CButtonDialer, CButton)
    ON_WM_THEMECHANGED()
    ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
    ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CButtonDialer message handlers

void CButtonDialer::PreSubclassWindow()
{
    OpenTheme();

    HFONT hFont = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
    LOGFONT lf;
    GetObject(hFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf);
    lf.lfHeight = 14;
    StringCchCopy(lf.lfFaceName,LF_FACESIZE,_T("Microsoft Sans Serif"));
    m_FontLetters.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

    DWORD dwStyle = ::GetClassLong(m_hWnd, GCL_STYLE);
    dwStyle &= ~CS_DBLCLKS;
    ::SetClassLong(m_hWnd, GCL_STYLE, dwStyle);
}

LRESULT CButtonDialer::OnThemeChanged() 
{
    CloseTheme();
    OpenTheme();
    return 0L;
}

void CButtonDialer::OnSize(UINT type, int w, int h)
{
    CButton::OnSize(type, w, h);
}

void CButtonDialer::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags,CPoint point)
{
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    if (rect.PtInRect(point)) {
        if (GetCapture() != this) {
            SetCapture();
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    else {
        ReleaseCapture();
        Invalidate();
    }
    CButton::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}

void CButtonDialer::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct) 
{
    CDC dc;
    dc.Attach(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);       //Get device context object
    CRect rt;

    rt = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem;      //Get button rect
    dc.FillSolidRect(rt,dc.GetBkColor());
    dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

    CRect rtl = rt;
    UINT state = lpDrawItemStruct->itemState;   //Get state of the button

    if (!m_hTheme) {
        UINT uStyle = DFCS_BUTTONPUSH;
        if ( (state & ODS_SELECTED) ) {
            uStyle |= DFCS_PUSHED;
            rtl.left+=1;
            rtl.top+=1;
        }
        dc.DrawFrameControl(rt, DFC_BUTTON, uStyle);
    } else {
        UINT uStyleTheme = RBS_NORMAL;
        if ( (state & ODS_SELECTED) ) {
            uStyleTheme = PBS_PRESSED;
        } else if (GetCapture()==this) {
            uStyleTheme = PBS_HOT;
        }
        DrawThemeBackground(m_hTheme, dc.m_hDC,
            BP_PUSHBUTTON, uStyleTheme,
            rt, NULL);
    }

    CString strTemp;
    GetWindowText(strTemp);     // Get the caption which have been set

    rtl.top += 4;
    CString letters;
    COLORREF crOldColor;
    if (m_map.Lookup(strTemp,letters)) {
        rtl.left+=15;
        dc.DrawText(strTemp,rtl,DT_LEFT|DT_TOP|DT_SINGLELINE);      // Draw out the caption
        HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(dc.m_hDC, m_FontLetters);
        // Do your text drawing
        rtl.left += 13;
        rtl.top += 4;
        rtl.right -=4;
        crOldColor = dc.SetTextColor(RGB(148, 167, 70));
        dc.DrawText(letters,rtl,DT_LEFT | DT_TOP | DT_SINGLELINE);
        dc.SetTextColor(crOldColor);
        // Always select the old font back into the DC
        SelectObject(dc.m_hDC, hOldFont);
    } else {
        //127,127,127
        crOldColor = dc.SetTextColor(RGB(148, 167, 70));
        dc.DrawText(strTemp,rtl,DT_CENTER|DT_TOP|DT_SINGLELINE);        // Draw out the caption
        dc.SetTextColor(crOldColor);
    }

    if ( (state & ODS_FOCUS ) )       // If the button is focused
    {
        int iChange = 3;
        rt.top += iChange;
        rt.left += iChange;
        rt.right -= iChange;
        rt.bottom -= iChange;
        dc.DrawFocusRect(rt);
    }
    dc.Detach();
}

BOOL CButtonDialer::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    //255,255,255
    CBrush myBrush(RGB(173, 41, 41));    // dialog background color
    CBrush *pOld = pDC->SelectObject(&myBrush);
    BOOL bRes = pDC->PatBlt(0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), PATCOPY);
    pDC->SelectObject(pOld);    // restore old brush
    return bRes;                       // CDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
}
```

Comment: See `CMFCButton` and its `SetFaceColor` method.

Comment: is there any option available to change background color in the property window.

Comment: i have some doubts.please help me. i cant solve the solutions. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a message handler for the [`WM_ERASEBKGND` message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055(v=vs.85).aspx) and paint the background yourself.

Comment: @Mark.let me check it

Comment: Your answer is like a cannon to kill spiders!

Comment: @sergiol the Windows API is completely primitive, this is just the way it's done. I haven't used MFC extensively for many years though, I didn't know about `CMFCButton` that you mention in your answer. I'm sure if you check out the source this is exactly what it's doing.

Comment: @Mark.is there any option available to change background color in the property window

Comment: @MarkRansom : What is done is the button is declared as `BS_OWNERDRAW` in `PreSubclassWindow` and the drawing behavior is defined in `DrawItem`

Comment: @MarkRansom. please ping me in skype.my skype id : prince tomy. i am working in microsip project.i want to change the ui of microsip done in mfc frameworks.

Comment: @Prince sorry I'm not a consulting service, I won't be pinging you. But I will give you a piece of advice: Microsoft's facilities are meant for mainstream applications, and deviating from their intended use or look will involve lots of work. You may want to investigate other frameworks.

Comment: @MarkRansom.ok sir.

Comment: @MarkRansom.i have been edited my question.i have shared  my source code.please check this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put a normal button on the Resource Editor.
2. On the .h file of the form where you use it, declare a `CMFCButton` variable like `m_btnRead`.
3. In the `DoDataExchange` method of your form append a line

   ```
   DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON_READ, m_btnRead);
   ```
4. On the method where you initialize your form (`OnInitDialog`, `Create`, etc.) append a line

   ```
   m_btnRead.SetFaceColor(RGB(0, 255, 255));
   ```

and now you are done!

Comment: @sergiol.sir can you ping me , my skype id : prince tomy

Comment: Not very helpful to set the back color of a button, indeed!

Comment: @sergiol.is there any option available to change background color in the property window

Comment: i think that will be very easy for a new one.

Comment: i am a fresher in mfc framework.Any option available to change ui settings in the property windows.

Comment: @sergiol.please ping me .my skype id:prince tomy

Comment: I recommend you to download [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Sample Library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5718) and see how they do it

Comment: @sergiol.sir this is microsip project ui .i want to change the ui.

Comment: @sergiol.please help me sir.please ping me

Comment: skype id: prince tomy

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? Stack overflow is not a "do my homework" service!

Comment: @sergiol.sorry sir.i can share my codes,thats why i am asking for that type of help.i never repeat it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170551/discussion-between-sergiol-and-prince).